# Home-assistant, raspberry, No access to /dev/mem

Tags: raspberry-pi, home-assistant

Problem with "No access to /dev/mem."
I have HA in docker container on raspberry pi 4.
I can read temperature from the one wire  sensor (GPIO4).

```
sensor:
  - platform: onewire
    names:
     28-3c01f09519d1: Sensor1
```

But when i wanted to manage gpio i get error.

```
switch:
  - platform: rpi_gpio
    ports:
      16: light
```

Error:
"Error while setting up rpi_gpio platform for switch.
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!"
In docker I tried to set:

```
   privileged: true
     command: ["--privileged"]
     devices:
       - /dev/mem:/dev/mem
       - /dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem
     volumes:
       - /home/pi/homeassistant:/config
       - /dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem
       - /dev/mem:/dev/mem
```

And I add user pi to group gpio.
But nothing helps ... 
Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you really have spaces in those paths?

Comment: oops i don't have it, it's a formatting error, i can't join them now

Comment: Hmmm... Have you tried what it suggests, running the command in the container as root? Normally this shouldn't be required any more, though.

Comment: FYI There is also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ which may be helpful.

Comment: yes i tried everything. Download the latest system image and turn it on the docker again and it works for now. We'll see how long ...